# Show that $x! y! = z!$ has infinitely many solutions. (Hint: For example, $5! 119! = 120!$.)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, factorial

Show that

> $$x! ·y! = z!$$

has infinitely many solutions. (Hint: For example, $5! 119! = 120!$)

I am stuck on this problem. Within this section we are learning Congruence. So I know it involves something with mods.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. When you asked the question, a link was given to [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). In its present form, this question is unsuitable for the site, because it lacks context. You can edit the post to improve it - please add the source and motivation of the problem as well as your current thoughts about solving it.  Also, please ensure the question is not only stated in the title.

Comment: Hint of an easy way to generate infinitely many solutions: set $x=1$.

Comment: The hint should spell it out quite clearly what's going on. As an additional example, 4!23!=24! Consider the relationship between 4!, 23 and 24.  "I know it has something to do with congruence and mods" I wouldn't say so... I think of it more directly.  This has more to do with equality than with congruence.  Note, the final proof will likely require induction.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=p!$ for some $p\in\mathbb N$.

Observe now that

> $$a·(a-1)!=a!\iff p!·(a-1)!=a!$$

which has infinitely many solutions

Answer (score 0):

The hint leads you to recognize that $2!1!=2!, 3!5!=6!, 4!23!=24!, 5!119!=120!, 6!719!=720!$ etc...

In general $n!(n!-1)!=(n!)!$

This is readily apparent that it is true.  Arguably, an induction proof isn't even necessary as it can be shown directly.  Remember that $k\times (k-1)! = k!$ for all natural $k$.  Now, apply this for the case when $k$ happens to be $n!$.

Finally, recognize the connection to your originally phrased problem and conclude that since the above identity works for all natural $n$, there are infinitely many (non-trivial) solutions to $x!y!=z!$